# Переход по страницам без перезагрузки всей страницы. AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, использую библиотеку ['jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)'.
Столкнулся с проблемой,

1. C главной страницы на вторую переходит нормально, а  вернуться на главную ,уже перезагружает всю страницу.
2. На обеих страницах есть слайдер. НО на второй странице слайдер не работает.

В чем проблема?

Код второй страницы

```
<!--HOME SLIDER-->
        <section class="section vh100">
            <div class="homeSlider slider" id="homeSlider">
                <!--SLIDE#1-->
                <div class="slideItem vh100" style="background-color: green">
                    <div class="headWrapper headWrapper__center">
                        <hgroup class="head-title">
                        <h1 class="head-title__title title big-title">PAGE 2</h1>

                    </hgroup>
                     </div>

                </div>
                <!--END SLIDE#1-->
                <!--SLIDE#2-->
                <div class="slideItem vh100" style="background-color: yellow">
                    <div class="headWrapper headWrapper__center">
                         <hgroup class="head-title">
                        <h1 class="head-title__title title big-title">PAGE 2</h1>

                     </hgroup>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--END SLIDE#2-->
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--END HOME SLIDER-->
```

Пробовал вставлять всю страницу и подключать там стили и js , но тогда ajax переход вообще не работает

JS

```
   $(function(){
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container')

});
```

Посмотреть пример работы сайта  можно **[здесь](https://glog1.github.io/testajax)**

Comment: имхо лучше используй [какой-нибудь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/321844/) [spa](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Одностраничное_приложение) фреймворк, так как эта библиотека не сильно развивается (в readme написано, что она `largely unmainteined`)